# Autoencoder in Keras with low Validation loss but reconstruction is just a noise

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, compression, autoencoder

I am trying to compress a timewave by using autoencoder. I am using the below-mentioned architecture.

```
#input_wave = Input(shape=(7500,))
encoded_1 = Dense(1000, activation='tanh',input_shape=(7500,))
encoded_2 = Dense(500, activation='tanh')
encoded_3 = Dense(300, activation='tanh')
encoded_4 = Dense(128, activation='tanh')

decoded_3 = Dense(300, activation='tanh')
decoded_2 = Dense(500, activation='tanh')
decoded_1 = Dense(1000, activation='tanh')
decoded_0 = Dense(7500, activation='linear')
```

This is the loss function am using

```
#autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')

autoencoder.fit(x_train, x_train,
            epochs=15,
            batch_size=300,
            shuffle=True,
            validation_data=(x_test, x_test),
            callbacks=[TensorBoard(log_dir='/tmp/autoencoder')])
```

and this is how my validation score looks like. 
[my validation scores](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6u3q.png)

but when I try to use predict and reconstruct the wave it appears to be just a noise. 
[Predicted and real timewave](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vitx.png)

what am I doing wrong? any leads will be highly appreciated.

**update:**
after changing the loss function to MSE and optimizer to adam i saw the network overfitting. Validation loss never goes down significantly. please look at the attached screenshot. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uYz4.png)

**Update**
I shortend the length of my Data to 2500 and it start working. I think my model was not sophisticated enough to compress the 7500 to 128 or maybe it is just not possible. So i use 3 separate models to compress the data. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Your loss values are negative, that's not right, you probably are using the wrong loss function, MSE seems more appropriate.

Comment: I recommend using MSE as you loss function. Also, try changing optimizer to `adam`. If the situation is not improving try smaller learning rate.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I read online that loss values can be -ve and this has nothing to do with the performance because it is just a number. But thanks for the suggestion let me apply these changes.

Comment: @AliRaza No, that is wrong, losses should not be negative. Here you got negative values because you used binary cross-entropy with network outputs that are not in the [0, 1] range. That's why I pointed the inconsistency.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegroI got your point and I did change the loss to MSE but now the network is overfitting. validation Loss never goes below 0.9 and after some iteration, it starts increasing. Please check the update in the question. Thanks a lot for your help so far :)

Comment: @SreeramTP network started overfitting please check the image attached in the update. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: Have you normalized and prepared data properly.?. And why you use `tanh` as activation of hidden layers.?

Comment: @SreeramTP yes I do scale the data with mean zero and variance 1. I use tanh because my data contains -ve values I cant use relu because then it will not consider the information in the negative part of the signal.

Comment: @AliRaza only your last layer needs to be able to produce negative output. All other layers can safely use relu. No guarantee that this helps, though. Also, as your data is scaled to `[-1,1]` already, I would try `tanh` in the last layer and then scale up the result manually.